# Effect of calling destructor of boost::lock's?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

Does calling a destructor of an `boost::lock` object explicitly have any consequence at all?

For instance:

```
boost::mutex M_;
boost::mutex::scoped_lock SL_(M_);
SL_.~unique_lock();

SL_.unlock();
SL_.lock();
//both of the above work on runtime as if nothing happened to SL_
//note: typedef unique_lock<mutex> scoped_lock;
```

Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Why would you want to use a `scoped_lock` if you want to delete it by yourself anyway? The great advantage of those boost locks is that they manage themselfes. Otherwise you could just call `M_.lock()` and don't use the `lock` class itself anyway.

Comment: @Toby: "out of curiosity". I know what these objects are for, and what the intended use is, but I just want to push a few limits to have a better feeling of them. "Manage themselves" means something will be called automatically, and I'd better know exactly what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SL_.~unique_lock();
```

Once you call the destructor of an object allocated on local storage, it is not alive anymore.
Referring to the object members after calling the destructor is an **Undefined Behavior**.

An Undefined Behavior means that any behavior is possible and does not necessarily mean that your code crashes, but it means you can see incorrect behavior or any random behavior.
So just don't do that.

Comment: OK - so I ran into this usual simple trap. Thx for pointing out. BTW - is TH local storage synonymous with the local stack created for each TH? I'm asking, because in an example I'm playing with I'm passing boost::ref's to boost::lock objects between threads... and now wonder if this can lead to - again - some luckily-working code; specifically I lock SL_, pass it via boost::thread TH_(THfoo,boost::ref(SL_)); to a THread, where I SL_.unlock() - which seems to be working OK.

Comment: @PMarecki: Yes, local storage = stack. If you are passing the address of the stack allocated variable to thread then you should ensure that the variable remains alive in the thread in which it was created till the thread to which it was passed is done using it.However, if you are passing a copy of the variable to the thread then it is all good.

Answer (score 3):

Calling a destructor of a stack-allocated object explicitly is a Very Bad Idea (tm). The reason is once the destructor starts the object technically no longer exists but C++ is unaware and will call the destructor again when the object goes out of scope and this will lead to undefined behavior. Also doing anything else (like calling a member function) on such object is also undefined behavior. So you can't expect any reasonable behavior from the described setup, just don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for answer; please consider my comment to Als as directed to you too. Thx.

Comment: Yes, usually "the automatic storage" for objects you take addresses of is the stack of the thread by which the object is allocated. So if you pass the object address to another thread you'd better be sure that the object is not destroyed before the other thread finished accessing it.